# Firebase Accessing Snapshot Value Error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I recently upgraded to swift 3 and have been getting an error when trying to access certain things from a snapshot observe event value.

My code:

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let username = snapshot.value!["fullName"] as! String
    let homeAddress = snapshot.value!["homeAddress"] as! [Double]
    let email = snapshot.value!["email"] as! String
}
```

The error is around the three variables stated above and states:

Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that you probably need to cast your `snapshot.value` as a `NSDictionary`.

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let username = value?["fullName"] as? String ?? ""
    let homeAddress = value?["homeAddress"] as? [Double] ?? []
    let email = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""

}
```

You can take a look on firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Answer (score 8):

When Firebase returns data, `snapshot.value` is of type `Any?` so as you as the developer can choose to cast it to whatever data type you desire. This means that `snapshot.value` can be anything from a simple Int to even function types.

Since we know that Firebase Database uses a JSON-tree; pretty much key/value pairing, then you need to cast your `snapshot.value` to a dictionary as shown below.

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let firebaseDic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] // unwrap it since its an optional
    {
       let username = firebaseDic["fullName"] as! String
       let homeAddress = firebaseDic["homeAddress"] as! [Double]
       let email = firebaseDic["email"] as! String

    }
    else
    {
      print("Error retrieving FrB data") // snapshot value is nil
    }
}
```