# using swift 3 how to retrive data inside another data from firebase

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm trying to fetch data in a specific data such in age_range inside the 'min' which equal to 21 
although 'total' inside 'summary' that is inside friends. 
i only success fetching normal data such as name and gender ....
your help would be much appreciable

Comment: so, what is your question? how to get data from friends/summary/total? or what?

Comment: yeah im trying to get the data inside a data and save it as a dictonary maybe

Comment: Please post Firebase structures as text please, no images. Images are not searchable and if we need to use the structure in the answer, we have to retype it. You can get your Firebase structure from the Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just observe the parent node (which brings in all of the child data) and get the info you need from there? It's a one-call-does-it-all kind of thing and while it does pull more data, it also gives you access to everything within the node without multiple Firebase calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3 & Xcode 8.3.2**

I hope this code will solve your problem

```
    // Create constant of baseURL (Make your life easier)
    let baseURl = Database.database().reference()

    // create reference that u want to fetch
    let refToFetch = baseURl.child("users").child("uid").child("FB result").child("age_range")

    // fetch the value
    refToFetch.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // do something with value for key "min"
        print(snapshot.value(forKey: "min") ?? "no value")
        if let value: Int = snapshot.value(forKey: "min") as? Int {
            // You got the value
            print("value of min is: \(value)")
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error, "Failed to fetch value")
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error? Show me your console, so i can fix that for you

Comment: @OT AMD I edited my answer, so it will more clear for you... please up vote if my answer is worked for you, thank u

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you want to retrieve data from the child of a child.

```
ref?.child("users").child(uid).child("youCanAddAsManyOfTheseAsYouWishToAccessChildrenOfChildren").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      //you can either access children in the line above or by:
      snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "childName").value
})
```

If this is not the answer to your question just comment below.

edit: Here is an exact example for you.

```
ref?.child("users").child(uid).child("FB result").child("age_range").child("min").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      //you can either access children in the line above or by:
      print(snapshot.value)
})
```

Comment: nearly my answer but i couldn't success so far ... please help me get an examply of how to replace this : "youCanAddAsManyOfTheseAsYouWishToAccessChildrenOfChildren" if i want to get the value of 21 !

Comment: @OTAMD I edited my response

Comment: @OTAMD You could also access children by path using `ref.child("users/uid/FB result/age_range/min")`. You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40567781/4962554) answer useful in understanding Firebase's structure.